# Ionic/cordova android emulate broken - shows some angular code

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

Newb alert. I'm attempting to build my first ios/android app. It's an angular 1 based app and I'm using ionic to build the ios and android versions.  I've got the app working in regular browsers.  I've built the IOS version and tested it, and it works.  Once I build the android version and test in various virtual or a real device, all that shows is a bit of code.  Here's the debug log:

```
 03-03 07:16:53.908 2764-2775/com.example.myuser.myapplication E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
 03-03 07:16:54.845 2764-2847/com.example.myuser.myapplication E/EGL_emulation: tid 2847: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

**ionic serve --lab** works fine and shows ios and android (image attached)

In the 2nd image (the android virtual device) you can see a few pieces of angular code.

[image: android emulator]
[image: ionic lab]

Comment: The debug log appears to be incomplete. Another thing that can be worth trying is to bring up Chrome's inspector to see if there are any other errors being thrown by the WebView. Enter `chrome:inspect` in the browser address bar. Your emulator should be visible and you should be able to inspect it.

Comment: Fantastic Firoze.  I knew I could use chrome inspect for browser debugging, but not for android emulator debugging.  There are MANY 404's for referenced files.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue and hope this helps anyone else who has the same problem.  After checking the chrome dev tools on the emulator or the actual android device I found 404 errors for all http/https requests. I had to add the cordova whitelist plugin. I added that in my ionic folder:

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Others who have had this issue said they had to put some code in their index.html head section, but I did not do that.

So the plugin apparently made the device/emulator allow http requests and all the javascript libraries and css files that were 404's were found and the app worked!

A discussion for another question now becomes apparent, regarding external js libraries in an app. I'm thinking I should concat them all and include that instead of using http requests.